# Fourier integration of $f(x)=\pi e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've tried below Fourier integration and reached some answer.I would appreciate if anyone takes a look at this and enlighten me if something is wrong (or if it is right):

$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\pi e^{-x} & x>0 \\ 0 & x<0 \end{cases}
$

My answers are :

$
A(w)=\dfrac{1}{1+w^{2}}
$

$
B(w)=\dfrac{w}{1+w^{2}}
$

finally :

$
f(x)=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{1+w^{2}} cos(wx)+\dfrac{w}{1+w^{2}}sin(wx)dx
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-a \:x}dx=\frac1a,\qquad \Re a>0. \tag1
$$
Then, for any $w \in \mathbb{R}$, you have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\:e^{-i\:w \:x}\:dx=\int_0^{+\infty}\pi e^{-a \:x}e^{-i\:w \:x}\:dx= \pi\:\frac1{1+w^2}-i \pi\:\frac{  w}{1+w^2}.
$$

Comment: I don't have to solve latest integration my will is to find true values for $A(w)$ and $B(w)$ (Looks like we have reached same result for them) , and also thank you for answer

Comment: @sajjad Ok, thanks!